# Picasso to load byte array

Tags: android, file-upload, picasso

I need to load a bitmap, that is in the file system, into byte array to upload it but needs to be:

- Resized to 500x500 and in bytes[].
- Async

I can do it with glide

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(“/user/profile/photo/path”)
    .asBitmap()
    .toBytes()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<byte[]>(250, 250) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(byte[] data, GlideAnimation anim) {
            // Post your bytes to a background thread and upload them here.
        }
    });
```

but I dont want to include it just for that.
Any way to do it with picasso?

Comment: `a bitmap, that is in the file system`. ??? How that is possible? Please give an example.

Comment: @greenapps I am in the same situation. In my case I get a an image as a string (base64 encoded) and i want to display it with a library (to get performance optimizations).

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); 
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: But I need it async, so Glide have a way to do it easy and I was asking if there is one with picasso.

Comment: Resize Bitmap first "Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false));" and then convert to bytes

Comment: Enclose this code in a asynctask. you can find good tutorials for it here. http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/